# When using uuid in aws lambda results undefined in logs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, uuid, serverless-framework

I am using `uuid` in my lambda as:

```
import uuid from 'uuid';

Item: {
  userId: uuid.v4(),
  name: '',
  email: '',
}
```

When the lambda get triggered it results following error.

> ERROR Invoke Error     {
>       "errorType": "TypeError",
>       "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'v4' of undefined",
>       .... }

How do I fix this.

UUID version: **7.0.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending hours found that the latest version of uuid has a breaking change. Hope this would help anyone who is facing the same problem.

If you are importing  and using uuid as

```
import uuid from 'uuid';

id: uuid.v4()
```

This won't work anymore

as per the document [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid/v/7.0.1)

You will need to import it as

```
import { v4 } from 'uuid';
```

or use a custom namespace

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using node 14.x, AWS Lambda as follows:

```
const {v4} = require('uuid');
const uuidCode = v4();
```